# CakePhp: Prevent duplicate calls which insert at the same time same information

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Im using CakePhp as a middle API which syncs up inventories in different marketplaces and saves the orders history. When an order is made on one marketplace it updates the inventory on the other marketplace and vice versa. Right now I have a notification from one of the marketplaces which tells my API a order just came in. Problem is this notifications is sent two separate times with exactly the same information at the same time. My API runs this two separate calles at the same time and generates two inserts. I do have a code which checks that the Order_ID from the incoming order is not duplicated on the table where I save the order history it insert into. BUT since the calls are made at exactly the same time, when the code checks if the Order_ID exists, it does not so it creates two different inserts and the order get duplicated.

The notification is almost identical, I receive this:

```
{  
   "resource":"\/orders\/order_id",
   "user_id":"user_id",
   "topic‌​":"orders",
   "applicat‌​ion_id":idhere,
   "atte‌​mpts":1,
   "sent":"2016‌​-07-26T14:34:00.342Z‌​",
   "received":"2016-0‌​7-26T14:34:00.338Z"
}‌
```

On one notification and the other has the same information but with less then 1 second of difference between sent and received from the first notification. With that i use the order_id to call the information from the order and save it into history table.

What I need is a way to either delay one from happening so the check I have works fine or another way to check for duplicate order_id. It worth noting that its not two inserts in one call. There are two separated notifications calls, which make it hard for my code to really get when one is duplicated. Any ideas what I could try?

Comment: Show the requests, the best a a complete request dump taken with a tool like Charles Proxy. Are they for sure identical? I'm pretty sure it is possible to figure out which of both requests came in first and compare them with a previous request. Another solution might be to stack the requests and process them in a queue one by one after each other.

Comment: The notification is almost identical, I recibe this: ´{"resource":"\/orders\/order_id","user_id":"user_id","topic":"orders","application_id":idhere,"attempts":1,"sent":"2016-07-26T14:34:00.342Z","received":"2016-07-26T14:34:00.338Z"}´ on one notification and the other has the same information but with less then 1 second of difference between sent and received from the first notification. With that i use the order_id to call the information from the order and save it into history table.

Comment: Use the isUnique() rule in your model and on top of that add an unique index to the DB itself. Doesn't this already solve the problem? If no, why? What happens then? If you use transactions try to commit after each save so it doesn't try to save multiple, possible duplicate rows, in one transaction.

Comment: Yup Indeed that was it. I didnt have the order_id as a unique index, I added the rules in the model and the DB. I think its working now haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's little ugly, but you could create unique index on Order_ID column in history table.

This way the insert with the same Order_ID won't succeed.

Comment: I thought of that hahaha but wasn't quite sure if it would work :P Ill give it a shot.